# SQL query -- no consistent key -- search multiple columns in one table based upon value in another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I am trying to join the `PRODUCTS` table with the `PROD_REF` table based upon multiple conditions. The problem is there isn't a consistent key to join these two tables.

The UPC code is unique to each item in `PROD_REF`, but there could be more than one match in the `PRODUCTS` table (or no match at all). And we want to test for a match on columns UPC1, UPC2, UPC3, UPC4, UPC5, and UPC6 from the `PRODUCTS` table with the `UPC` column in PROD_REF.

It gets further complicated because some (not all) of the UPC codes in the `PROD_REF` table have a leading zero. So we need to consider if the "UPC n" codes from `PRODUCTS` is "contained in" the UPC code in `PROD_REF`. If no match can be found then we bump down to consider the combination Manufacturer name and Part # and hope we get a match.

This also gets a little tricky in that often there is only a partial match with the Manufacturer name, but always an exact match with the Part #.  (But, more than one manufacturer could have the same part number associated with their product.)

So, anyone want to help me tackle this beast? :)  Thanks in advance.

- The PROD_REF table is ~ 3million rows.
- Thee PRODUCTS table is ~ 16K rows.

We can put indexes and such wherever we want.

[PRODUCTS]

```
 ID UPC 1       UPC 2       UPC 3       UPC 4   UPC 5   UPC 6   Manufacturer        Manufacturer Part #
 1  78698502014 7869850201  78698404301 NULL    NULL    NULL    RADIATOR SPECIALTY  EB1
 16 78698718101 7869845980  78698459806 NULL    NULL    NULL    RADIATOR SPECIALTY  GR1
 17 45408020007 4540802000  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    MAASDAM             144SB-6
 18 45408010008 4540801000  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    MAASDAM             144S-6 1
 19 79843002137 7757801495  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    FROST KING          3A59
 27 36448124640 3644812464  2906970464  NULL    NULL    NULL    FRANKLIN ELECTRIC P 11010Y152
```

[PROD_REF]

```
 ITEM_PIK   UPC             MFR_FULLNAME        MFR_CAT_NUM     MFR_DESCRIPTION     PRODUCT_NAME
 510        78698502014     RADIATOR SPECIALTY  EB1             SUBMERSIBLE         PUMP <-- 1*
 512        78698459806     RADIATOR SPECIALTY  GR1             SUBMERSIBLE         PUMP <-- 2*
 513        045408020007    MAASDAM             144SB-6         DUAL PURPOSE        PUMP <-- 3*
 516        7757801495      FROST KING / EXTRA  3A59            DUAL PURPOSE        PUMP <-- 4*
```

- (*1) Match UPC 1
- (*2) Match UPC 3
- (*3) UPC 1 is contained in (leading zeros)
- (*4) If No UPC match, then match by Manufacturer (Full or partial name match) and Part #

**Just to add a little more context.**
I left out a few details on the PROD_REF Table -- it would also include Description Details, Image_URL, and some other items.

The output ideally would look something like the following:

```
      ID    ITEM_PIK    UPC 1       UPC 2       UPC 3       UPC 4   UPC 5   UPC 6   MFR_FULLNAME        PRODUCT_NAME    MFR_CAT_NUM     DESCRIPTION_DETAILS     IMAGE_URL
      1     510         78698502014 7869850201  78698404301 NULL    NULL    NULL    RADIATOR SPECIALTY  PUMP            EB1             Blah, blah, blah        www.abc.com/images/123abc.jpg
      16    512         78698718101 7869845980  78698459806 NULL    NULL    NULL    RADIATOR SPECIALTY  PUMP            GR1             Blah, blah, blah        www.abc.com/images/456abc.jpg
      17    513         45408020007 4540802000  NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL    MAASDAM             PUMP            144SB-6         Blah, blah, blah        www.abc.com/images/789abc.jpg
```

OR, I would be happy with just a single column with UPC code match (if there is one); so somthing like:

```
      ID    ITEM_PIK    UPC         MFR_FULLNAME        PRODUCT_NAME    MFR_CAT_NUM     DESCRIPTION_DETAILS     IMAGE_URL
      1     510         78698502014 RADIATOR SPECIALTY  PUMP            EB1             Blah, blah, blah        www.abc.com/images/123abc.jpg
      16    512         78698718101 RADIATOR SPECIALTY  PUMP            GR1             Blah, blah, blah        www.abc.com/images/456abc.jpg
      17    513         45408020007 MAASDAM             PUMP            144SB-6         Blah, blah, blah        www.abc.com/images/789abc.jpg
```

Comment: With the sample table, could you provide what does your expected result look like?

Comment: It is not completely clear how comparison works if there is a leading zero. Can you please post what you tried so far.

Comment: Well, that is partly what makes this so complicated (at least for me) is the conditional comparison -- so in the case of the UPC code fields the reference might have 01234 and the product table would have 1234 ==> so to get a match you would have to say "give me everything where a UPC number for PRODUCTS is included in the UPC code for PROD_REF".  One of the things I tried was an inner join: "JOIN TABLE b ON b.column LIKE '%'+ a.column +'%' "  That worked, but super slow and then I also got bogged down with the other conditionals.

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best or most pretty solution, but I am thinking something like this? For the first part at least.

```
SELECT
  ID
  ,ITEM_PIK
  ,UPC1
  ,UPC2
  ,UPC3
  ,UPC4
  ,UPC5
  ,UPC6
  ,MFR_FULLNAME
  ,PRODCUT_NAME
  ,MFR
  ,case when B.PRODUCT_NAME is null then
      case when C.PRODUCT_NAME is null then
         case when D.Product_name is null then
              ..
         else
             d.product_name
         end
      else
        c.product_name
      end
     else
      b.product_name
    end as [Product_Name]
FROM
  PRODUCTS A
  left join [PROD_REF] B ON (A.UPC1 = B.UPC)
  left join [PROD_REF] C ON (A.UPC2 = C.UPC)
  left join [PROD_REF] D ON (A.UPC3 = D.UPC)
  left join [PROD_REF] E ON (A.UPC4 = E.UPC)
  left join [PROD_REF] F ON (A.UPC5 = F.UPC)
  left join [PROD_REF] G ON (A.UPC6 = G.UPC)
```

Comment: Thanks for the try -- PRODUCT_NAME isn't a field we're trying to compare.  And then the UPC codes are straight joins (which is fine when they match), but doesn't do anything to consider the case where the UPC code in PROD_REF may have a leading zero.

Comment: Product_Name was just an example.. Would be same procedure for every field.     When you have a leading zero why not try something like right(UPC, Len(UPC) - 1)? Sure you do not know when it may have it, but you can come around this using a case statement?